# RabbitMQ on Linux RHEL internal memory path mapping to another location

Tags: linux, memory, rabbitmq, queue, rhel

I have setup RabbitMQ on RHEL server. However, I want to know where it internally stores the queue data. I need it to be mapped to a storage that is reliable and has enough space to handle the load.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does RabbitMQ actually store the message physically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444425/how-does-rabbitmq-actually-store-the-message-physically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the internal database for persistent messages. RabbitMQ stores messages in memory by default.

The location of the persistent data store is the `RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR`. Specifically, that is located by default in `$RABBITMQ_HOME/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/$RABBITMQ_NODENAME`.

See [this page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html) for additional details.