# What kind of data structure message in disk when RabbitMQ store with persistent mode?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm using Rabbitmq docker images with version: `rabbitmq:3-management`.

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name ecomm-rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

And I'm curious about the way it stores msg in the queue (in case of persistent data in *disk* instead of *RAM*).

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444425/how-does-rabbitmq-actually-store-the-message-physically) and the accepted answer said that:

> RabbitMQ uses a custom DB to store the messages, the DB is usually
> located here:

```
/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@hostname/queues
```

However, when I navigate to this folder, I didn't see that.

**My question is:** What is the folder/file it storing the DB file? And what does kind of or structure look like?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question, check section `RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR` [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html). Here are the default values unless `RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR` is set explicitly.

> - Generic UNIX package: `$RABBITMQ_HOME/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia`
> - Ubuntu and Debian packages: `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/`
> - RPM: `/var/lib/rabbitmq/plugins`
> - MacOS (Homebrew): `${install_prefix}/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia`, the Homebrew prefix is usually `/usr/local`
> - Windows: `%APPDATA%\RabbitMQ`

You will see some `.dcd` and `.dcl` files. Meaning we have a [mnesia database](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_overview.html#the-mnesia-database-management-system). To verify that,

```sh
> erl -mnesia dir '"/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@YOUR_CONTAINER_ID"'
1> mnesia:start().
ok
2> mnesia:system_info().
# here you will see tables like `rabbit_durable_exchange`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what are the filename and content look like?

Comment: the `.dcd` and `.dcl` files in this folder, I believe they are part of [The Mnesia Database Management System](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_overview.html#the-mnesia-database-management-system)

Comment: Awesome. Could you pls update your answer along with a sample? I would really appreciate it.